# Node.js error handling

Tags: ajax, node.js, response

I am building an app using node.js and knex for the ORM. I want my insert command to send either a success or error response, but it is not working for some reason:

```
knex('reports').insert({
    reportid: reportId,
    created_at: currentDate 
}).then().catch(function(error) {
    if(error) {
        console.log("error!!!: " + error)
        res.send(400, error);
    } else {
        console.log('no error');
        res.send(200);
    }
});
```

The code as is does NOT console.log out the error nor lack of error.

Note - the `res.send(200)` should go back to my client side to alert the client the request was successful.

Can someone help? Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Probably because .catch only runs when there IS an error.

Comment: i see.. aside from `.catch` what else can I use to get the desired effect?

Comment: use .then to handle the success, and .catch for errors.

Comment: Read up on [Promises](http://knexjs.org/#Interfaces-Promises) for Knex.

Answer (score 2):

Promises will either trigger your `then` function or the `catch` function. Not both. Handling the success case happens in the `then` function, handling the error case happens in the `catch` function.

To demonstrate with your code:

```
knex('reports').insert({
    reportid: reportId,
    created_at: currentDate 
}).then(function(data) {
    console.log('no error');
    res.send(200);
}).catch(function(error) {
    console.log("error!!!: " + error)
    res.send(400, error);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should handle the positive flow within the .then part:

```
then()
{
        console.log('no error');
        res.send(200);
    }
```

Also it's not consider a good practice to mix DB code with HTTP related logic as they probably should reside in different layers/components, see best practice number 4 here:
http://goldbergyoni.com/checklist-best-practices-of-node-js-error-handling/